# Drupal module to require checkbox at login

Tags: drupal-6

For Drupal 6.x is there a module that makes it a requirement that the user check a check box before logging in?

The site needs to require every user to accept the Terms and Conditions at each login, not just at registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two modules, http://drupal.org/project/legal and http://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use, that require you to accept on registration (I guess you found those already).

What you need (accept on every login) is not a feature of those modules, as far as I know. However I think that is should not be too hard to write a custom module, re-using some of the code of one of those modules, that adds this checkbox to every login form.

If you have not written modules before, check out the [module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) on drupal.org. You will have to use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) to add a checkbox to the login form.

Answer (score 0):

@marcvangend thank you for the info and links, here is the code I found/edited/came up with:

```
function toscheckbox_form_user_login_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add a checkbox to login form about agreeing to terms of service.
  $form['terms_of_service'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox', 
    '#title' => "I agree with the website's terms of service.", 
    '#required' => TRUE
  );
}

function toscheckbox_form_user_login_block_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Add a checkbox to login form about agreeing to terms of service.
  $form['terms_of_service'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox', 
    '#title' => "I agree with the website's terms of service.", 
    '#required' => TRUE
  );
}
```

Comment: Does that really work as expected? Correct me it I'm wrong, but I think that `'#required' => TRUE` will only check if a valid value has been entered. For a checkbox, both 1 and 0 are valid values, so an unchecked box would still pass the #required test.

Comment: @marcvangend yes this worked for me. I tried checking and unchecking it, and I could not find a way to login without checking that box.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, when they log in, redirect them to a page that contains a little javascript.

Like so:

1) Create this trigger/action set:
[Trigger] User Logs In -> [Action] Redirect to /mustagree

2) Add content page mustagree:

if ( confirm('Terms: \n You must be older than 18 to enter. \n \n Do you agree to these terms?') ) {
     window.location = 'userhomepage'
}
else {
   window.location = 'logout'
}

Assuming you have a content page with the url userhomepage this will work perfectly.